# Select few fields as array in mongoose express

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose

If in my modle Schema data set i have...

```js
var visitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title                           : { type: String},
    client                          : { type: String},
    agenda                          : { type: String},
    agm                             : { type: String },
    anchor                          :{ type: String }
  )}
```

so here i want some other service which separate title, client, agenda into one array and agm,anchor into other array to retrive...
so i tried this way...

```js
function getExecsById(id){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log("im in getExecsById")
    var one = ('agm anchor');
    //var two =('title client agend');
    model
    .find({ _id: id })
    .select(one)
    .exec(function (err, item) {
        item = item.map(function(doc) { return doc.one; });
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
        else

            deferred.resolve(item);
    });
    return deferred.promise;

}
```

note: dont change schema...only in service separate data fields into two arrays and get the data.....

 do help  *thanks in advance*

Comment: `separate title, client, agenda into one array` what the data format of it? for each document like `[{title: 't1', client: 'c1', agenda: 'a1'}, {...}]` or for fields like `[title: ['t1', 't2'], client: ['c1', 'c2'], agenda: ['a1', 'a2', ...]]`?

Comment: [{title: 't1', client: 'c1', agenda: 'a1'}, {...}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that Lodash is available.

```
function getExecsById(id){
    var partition = ['agm', 'anchor'];

    return model.findOne({ _id: id })
        .then(function(item) {
            var p1 = [],
                p2 = [];

            return _.each(item, function(v, k) { 
                if (partition.indexOf(k) !== -1) {
                    p1.push(v);
                } 
                else {
                    p2.push(v);
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return error;
        });
}
```

Comment: thankyou ....but what are v and k here??? if i populate any field how to get der fields...

Comment: k is the data field name a and v is the data field value.